# Where can I read out the key press delay time

Tags: c++, gtk, gnome

When I press a key, there is a delay before the key is repeated again and again. I'm writing an application and need to know this delay time.

Where can I read out this delay time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keypress repeat delay is stored in dconf:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.keyboard delay
```

Comment: Seems like that setting is now deprecated. Need to use:

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.keyboard delay 250